# Alternatives ways to getting the properties of the file?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Background:

I have a file monitoring service that watches for changes in the files on the local system using the `FileSystemWatcher` class and i am handling for events like `Created`,`Deleted`,`Renamed`. When these events are triggered,I would simply want to GET THE PROPERTIES OF THE FILE such as `FileName`,`FileSize`,`CreationTime`,`LastAccessTime`,`LastWriteTime` using the `FileSystemInfo` class.

Problem:

While this service is running, I am unable to uninstall some programs for example (Microsoft Security Essentials). I have a feeling that these service is HANGING ON TO THE RESOURCES of the files marked for deletion because I can only uninstall those programs if only this service is running.

My Question is how can I `GET THE PROPERTIES OF THE FILE` (as specified above) in an `ALTERNATIVE` & efficient way `without hanging on to the resources of the file` ?

Here is my code using the `FileSystemInfo`

```
public void OnCreate/OnRenamed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)

{ FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath); 

String output = "<Event><TimeStamp>" + currentTime + "</TimeStamp>";
            output += "<Name>" + action + "</Name>";
            output += "<Properties><FileName>" + file.Name + "</FileName>";
            output += "<FullPath>" + file.FullName + "</FullPath>";
            output += "<FileSize>" + file.Length + "</FileSize>";
            output += "<CreationTime>" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.fff}", file.CreationTime) + "</CreationTime>";
            output += "<LastAccess>" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.fff}", file.LastAccessTime) + "</LastAccess>";
            output += "<LastWriteTime>" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.fff}", file.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now) + "</LastWriteTime></Properties></Event>";

}
```

Sincerely,
Derek

Comment: Fire up Process Explorer and see if you _really_ are hanging on to the files. No point in wild goose chasing.

Comment: Do advice me on how do I go about checking it ?

Comment: See [this](http://captaindbg.com/tutorial-and-advance-troubleshooting-using-process-explorer/). Scroll down to "Handle Level Troubleshooting"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [FileSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx#Y2174) will not normally 'hang on' to these files. You have to first figure out what exactly is causing other programs to stuck during uninstallation. Use [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what files are being accessed during uninstallation. The tool is pretty self explanatory, you need to filter on file system activity. Read [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/outlooking/archive/2010/05/13/useful-tools-while-troubleshooting-outlook-issues-2-process-monitor.aspx) or google around.

Try to experiment by taking out one thing at a time. I assume these programs get uninstalled successfully when your service is not running. This proves that it is indeed your service that is causing issues. First comment your FileSystemInfo code. See if the problem goes away. Then comment out FileSystemWatcher and see if it helps.

**Update**: looks like this is offending line:

```
file.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now
```

Try to comment this assignement and see if it solves the problem:

```
file.LastWriteTime /* = DateTime.Now */
```

Was this a typo or you really need to write LastWriteTime?

Comment: Do advice me on how do I go about checking it ?

Comment: @Derek: see updated answer, ProcessMonitor will do a better job than ProcessExplorer in this case. Or you can simply narrow down the reason by commenting code and checking if it helps.

Comment: Hmm,after commenting the section of the code on FileSystemInfo, programs are able to uninstall properly but I still cant figure out why this FileSystemInfo section of code (where i merely get the properties of the files while monitoring the system) would be the cause of the problem ?

Comment: I have posted the code in the edited question. Thanks in advance for your gracious help in finding out the problem.

Comment: @Derek: Nothing looks suspicious. However I see that this not all the code, some variables are not defined, LastAccessTime is not used etc. Try to comment smaller pieces of code and see if the problem goes away. Also provide more information on what software are you uninstalling and what exactly is happening during uninstallation.

Comment: @Derek: comment out LastWriteTime assignment and try again. See updated answer.

Comment: Haha indeed I realised if i tried to get the file properties of the LastWriteTime,Microsoft Security Essentials would inform me that an error code of 0X80070643 has prevented it from uninstalling.

Comment: Dear Sir, Maybe you could take a look at my another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184472/fileinfo-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is every interval check for LastAccessTime and LastWriteTime and do some quick math based on the interval and you can determine if the file was last accessed or modified within the interval time.  If it was, do what you have to do.  Just an idea...

Comment: Dear Sir, Maybe you could take a look at my another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184472/fileinfo-exceptions